# React: How to call function of new added child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a class component rendering multiple child components:

```
// inside my parent component
const allElements = arrayWithElements.map(elem => (
  <ChildElement title={elem.title} />
));


// my child component 
const ChildElement = ({title}) => {

  // log the title to the console
  const doSomething = () => {
    console.log(title);
  }

  return (
   <button type="button" onClick={doSomething}>{title}</button>
  );
}
```

My problem is that when I add a new element to the array "allElements", I want to execute my function "doSomething" one time just for the newly added element. I thought that there might be a solution by using refs, but afaik refs are not allowed in combination with function components, so can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3):

Access your children's methods is anti pattern. To achieve the described effect you could configure each `ChildComponent` to log only once on `mount`

```
const ChildElement = ({title}) => {

  //logging once in mount
  useEffect(() => console.log(title), [])

   const doSomething = () => {
    console.log(title);
  }

  return (
   <button type="button" onClick={doSomething}>{title}</button>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit nostalgic-bhaskara-lgv9l]

Comment: I thought of the same solution, but like that, doSomething runs also on the existing elements, not only on the newly added element

Comment: Wrap `ChildElement` with `React.memo` to prevent it to re render when `title` doesn't change

Comment: It works when the initial array is empty. But when doing `const [children, setChildren] = React.useState(["test"]);` it runs not only for the new added items but also for the existing one ("test" in this case). So how to omit the already existing items?

Comment: Did you used `React.memo` ?

Comment: Never used it before but it shall work like that right? `export default React.memo(ChildElement);` If so, then it doesn't work :/ Could you probably update the Sandbox to show how it shall work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198998/discussion-between-equalsound-and-dupocas).